# cluster position of record id is not static in oriendb

Tags: orientdb

I am new in orientdb-gremlin and recently, start playing with it. what I understood is orientdb stores the `record id` in `cluster: position` but when I retrieve the data from the database using `g.V()` the cluster position is not same. The example showed below.

query : `graph.addVertex(label, "Master", "title", "master")`

record id : `{'@value': '#60:-2', '@type': 'orient:ORecordId'}`

show id : `{'@value': '#21:3023', '@type': 'orient:ORecordId'}`

what I don't understand how the @value is being changed

Comment: Hi Akshay, which version of orientdb you use to do this test?

Comment: Orientdb- gremlin 3.0.2